# How to create a "framework" group and move frameworks therein

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, addition

I have added a bunch of frameworks to my app: Selected project, clicked "Build Phases," Clicked "Link Binary With Libraries," and then the "+" button to add them to the project.

They were automatically added to the top level of the hierarchy.

I then created a "framework" folder, and moved them therein with a simple drag n' drop.

Then they turned red. According to the following post, "The red text indicates that the actual files are not at the path that the project has for them."
[Frameworks are 'red' in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365114/frameworks-are-red-in-xcode)

How do I adjust this path, and/or correctly create a "framework" group within my project?

Answer (score 0):

If you move the framework files from within xcode into "yellow colored" groups, it does not update the actual file location, so that should not break anything.
See [Why are there some blue folders in my Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353274/why-are-there-some-blue-folders-in-my-xcode-project)

If you move the files from outside of xcode, like in finder, into another folder, xcode will lose the references and your frameworks in this case turn red.